# How to send two-dimensional array via ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays

I've got this method for sending data to the server:

```
var points = [];
var coords = polyline.geometry.getCoordinates();
for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++)
{
    var x = (coords[i][0]).toFixed(4);
    var y = (coords[i][1]).toFixed(4);
    points[i] = [x,y];
}
$("form").on('submit',
    function(e){
        var data = $(this).serializeArray();
        console.log(points);
        data.push({name:'points[]',value:points});
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/admin/index/add-route',
                method: 'post',
                data: data,
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log('succcess');
                }
            }
        );
        console.log(data);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
);
```

On the backend, I obtain a one-dimensional array with these values:

```
(var dump of $_POST['points'])
array (size=1)  0 => string '48.9225,24.6948,48.9220,24.7090' (length=31)
```

Comment: Did you try just using the array as data, without serializing it first ? And why are you pushing to the array after serializing it, serializeArray is for form elements ?

Comment: check my answer and this [JSFiddle] http://jsfiddle.net/tivie/J5nFS/3/

Answer (score 2):

Jquery will take multi dimensional arrays directly, no need to serialize.

var data = {
  foo:  123,
  bar:  456,
    rows: [
      {
        column1 : 'hello',
        column2 : 'hola',
        column3 : 'bonjour',.
      },
      {
        column1 : 'goodbye',
        column2 : 'hasta luego',
        column3 : 'au revoir',
      },
    ],
    test1:{
      test2: {
        test3:  'baz'
      }
    }
};
_Post Data in your PHP file would look like this

Array
   (
    [foo] => 123
    [bar] => 456
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [column1] => hello
                    [column2] => hola
                    [column3] => bonjour
                )

```
        [1] => Array
            (
                [column1] => goodbye
                [column2] => hasta luego
                [column3] => au revoir
            )

    )

[test1] => Array
    (
        [test2] => Array
            (
                [test3] => baz
            )

    )

)
```

Once you define your data multidimensional array, your Ajax could be as simple as

$.ajax({
          type:           'post',
          cache:          false,
          url:            './ajax.php',
          data:           data
      });
If your post array may have fields that you don't know about, you can access your Post array in your php file easily with

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($data, true);

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use .serializeArray();

Just do the following:

```
var data = {points: points};
```

and on the PHP side:

```
$points = json_decode($_POST['points']);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to pass the form data along with the points array

Answer (score 0):

To send an array to the server, use `JSON.stringify(object)`, resp. `JSON.stringify(array)` to convert an array or an object to a string. Use the same method from PHP to make an php-object (or array) from this string again: `json_decode(string)`

http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php

the other way round is `json_encode(data)` and parse it on the JS side: `JSON.parse(string)`

Answer (score 0):

It's seems you're doing something fishy. When you use serializeArray(), you convert a form to an object:

> .serializeArray() - Encode a set of form elements as an array of names
>   and values.

**[.serializeArray() docs](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)**

---

Also check this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tivie/J5nFS/3/)** with a mockup of your scenario (ajax was removed for obvious reasons).

---

Anyway, since you're already using jquery, and POST, use JSON to encode the array.

```
var data = $(this).serializeArray();
data.push({name:'points',value:points});
var dataJson = JSON.stringify(data);
```

then pass that in your ajax

On php side, you just need to parse the json

```
$data = json_decode($json_string);
```